# Python os.waitpid throw `[Errno 10] No child processes`

Tags: python

Following code return with `[Errno 10] No child processes` on windows platform (python version 2.7.2).

```
import subprocess
import os
pid = subprocess.Popen(["cmd"]).pid
os.waitpid(pid, 0)
print 'process %d finished' % pid
```

The same code works well on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maby this will work- but I have no idea, why your code isn't working on Windows- everything looks fine:

```
import subprocess
subp = subprocess.Popen(["cmd"])
subp.wait()
print 'process %d finished' % subp.pid
```

Comment: Yes, your code works. But I just cannot figure out what's wrong with my code. Could you reproduce my problem on your machine?

Comment: I don't have any Windows instalation so it'd be problem. But I think that maybe Windows doesn't assign pid immediately and you try to access it before assigning.

Comment: Finally I figured out why. os.waitpid take process handle as parameter, NOT process id.  This is really confusing. Anyway thanks a lot.